# Example of odm:query console command in Doctrine Mongo ODM

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

Is there any exemple of query command of the console tools in Doctrine ?
I tried it in a Symfony project the following way :

```
./app/console doc:mongo:query AcmeBundle:MyEntity {tag:1}
```

but it returns always the whole collection, tough only one record has tag "1".
I looked in the source code, it seems that the query must be in json format but I have no idea what is the right format, I guess it must be compatible with argument of find() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON format expects the key to be a string. Try {"tag": 1}.